# onItemClick, Intent, startActivity errors

Tags: java, android

My code:

```
package elf.app;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import elf.app.entity.ELFList;
import elf.app.entity.Entry;
import elf.app.test.FakeComm;

// TODO Kunna skicka att något är färdigt (ett rum är städat).

public class RoomListActivity extends ListActivity {
private ELFList eList;
//  private FakeComm fakecomm;
private Bundle extras;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    eList = new ELFList();

//      fakecomm = new FakeComm();
//      eList.add(fakecomm.getData());

    String[] strArr = {"asd","sdf","dfg"};
    eList.add(strArr);

    String[] str = eList.returnNames();


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, str));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Entry e = eList.getEntry(position);
            String roominfo = e.toString();


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RoomInfoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("entry",roominfo);
            this.startActivity(intent);

                // old stuff
            // String message;
            // message = eList.getEntryInfo(position);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

I'm getting errors at the following lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RoomInfoActivity.class);
```

and

```
this.startActivity(intent);
```

I don't have much of a clue why I get these errors, the exact output in the editor for these errors are:

- "The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class  ) is undefined"
- "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}"

I'm an Android newbie so please take that into consideration, however I have studied Java for about a year.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RoomInfoActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RoomListActivity.this, RoomInfoActivity.class);
```

The error is because by `this` you refer to OnClickListener. The problem is fixed, if you refer to the Activity's `this`. The second error is the same - wrong reference. Just remove `this`, and startActivity() method will be searched within the enclosing class too.

Comment: Thanks, the errors are gone. And thanks for the explaination Vladimir!

Comment: If it helps, try to upvote and accept the answer. Click the tick in the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RoomListActivity.this, RoomInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("entry",roominfo);
RoomListActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```