# Android startActivity OnItemClickListener() not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

I'm trying to start a new activity when an item in the listview is clicked, but it doesn't seem to work. Specifically, the onClick method is being called, and if I comment out the startActivity everything works fine, but that won't change the activity. So, I assume it has something to do with the Intent context
Here is the code:

```
public class ListViewRemovalAnimation extends Activity {

StableArrayAdapter mAdapter;
ListView mListView;
BackgroundContainer mBackgroundContainer;
boolean mSwiping = false;
boolean mItemPressed = false;
HashMap<Long, Integer> mItemIdTopMap = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

public List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_deletion);

    mBackgroundContainer = (BackgroundContainer) findViewById(R.id.listViewBackground);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    mAdapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.opaque_text_view, cheeseList,
            mTouchListener);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewRemovalAnimation.this, NewRecipe.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", recipes.get(position).toString());

            Gson gs = new Gson();
            String bookmarks;
            for (int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++) {
                bookmarks = gs.toJson(recipes.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("bookmarked" + i, bookmarks);
            }
            ListViewRemovalAnimation.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Yes, I have declared both activities in the android manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.feastbeast.MainActivity"
        android:label="Home" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.feastbeast.NewRecipe"
        android:label="Recipe" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.feastbeast.ListViewRemovalAnimation"
        android:label="Bookmarked" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

If needed you can check out the full code here: https://github.com/david-hong/feastBeast

I checked out the following, but neither seemed to work ([How do i use the OnItemClickListener to start a new intent based on which item is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610291/how-do-i-use-the-onitemclicklistener-to-start-a-new-intent-based-on-which-item-i) and [onItemClick, Intent, startActivity errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016793/onitemclick-intent-startactivity-errors)). I assume the second one doesnt work since the activity extends ListActivity and I'm extending Activity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Add logging to see if the listener is actually being called.  Then look at `NewRecipe` and make sure it's not immediately finishing.

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work.` please be specific.... This can be everything..

Comment: @Onik, I added the manifest code.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede , it seems that the listener is being called and that the onClick method is also called. How would I check to make sure that NewRecipe isn't immediately finishing?

Comment: See if it calls `finish()` anywhere.  Add more logging to its lifecycle methods to make sure it's being started at all.